# Problems with 3 way sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hi I think there may be a problem with my 3 way sort algorithm in the following Java program, also any suggestion on optimizing or just a simpler it would be greatly appreciated. The objective of the sort is to have the minus numbers first then zeros and then positive numbers

```
class ThreeWaySort
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int location = 0;

    int[] sArray = new int[50];

    for (int a = 25; a<= -24; a--) 
    {
        sArray[location] = a;
        location++;
    }

    int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 50;
    while (j!=k) 
    {
        if (sArray[j]==0) 
            {
                j++;
            }                           
        else if (sArray[j]<0) 
        {
            int t = sArray[i]; sArray[i] = sArray[j]; sArray[j] = t;        // case (ii)
            i++; j++;
        }
        else 
        {                                       
            k--;
            int t= sArray[j]; sArray[j] = sArray[k]; sArray[k] = t;
        }
    }

    for (int a = 0; a <= 49; a++) 
    {
        if(sArray[a] >-1)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(sArray[a] > 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.print(sArray[a] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

When i run the program as is it costantly print out a zero followed by three line instead of what I'm expecting to be, Numbers below zero in a line, followed by 3 blank lines then any zeros in the array, 3 blank lines, positive numbers in the array.

Comment: Input and output samples would help

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop that populates your array is incorrect:

```
for (int a = 25; a<= -24; a--)
```

The variable `a` starts at `25`, which is not less than or equal to `-24`, so the loop never executes.  You should use `>=`.

Comment: Also, the OP probably wants to do something with the output of their program. The two if statements in the final for loop aren't logical.

Comment: Never would have noticed that sorry to waste your time on something so trivial though